# Newly created WCF Project in VS2012 doesnt have service node in WebConfigs

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a new WCF project using Visual Studio 2012,
I noticed that there is no Service node in the `web.confi`g to define the service and the contract, however i deployed the service to azure and it worked, however I`m getting this error:

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large. In Silverlight
```

so i guess i need to increase the maximum allowed request but how do i do that with no service node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with VS 2010 WCF added the concept of default endpoints (as well as default bindings and behaviors), to simplify configuration.

The details can be found at this link: [A Developer's Introduction to Window's Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)

In your case, you'll need to create a binding in your config file that has larger sizes, and either set that as the default binding or assign that binding to an explicitly defined endpoint.

By default WCF (in .NET 4+) will assign request coming in over http to `basicHttpBinding`.  These protocol mappings can also be changed in the config file.

A couple of simple examples to help you (the article I linked goes into more detail):

To create a default binding, simply define the binding and omit the `name` attribute:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" ....>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This will make your supplied configuration the default `basicHttpBinding` for the service(s) using that config.

Alternatively, you can use the `name` attribute on a binding configuration and then assign it to an defined input.  Let's say you have a binding name "MyBinding":

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                     bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" 
                     contract="MyService.IMyContract" />
```

If you want something other than `basicHttpBinding` for http requests, you can do this in the protocols section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
```

The key in your situation is to you'll need to create the binding with larger values, and then either set it as the default or assign it to an endpoint (which you'll also need to define).

As I said, these are just simple examples to give you an idea, and there's a lot more detail in the article I linked.